# datagridview column copy to another datagridview column without duplicate

Tags: vb.net

How can I copy / clone a column from 1 DataGrid View to another DataGrid View without duplicate? Is there a way to do this? So far, I hadn't found any solution in Google regarding about this issue...any help would be greatly appreciated...

I am currently using vb.net to code in VisualStudio2019

Example

```
   DGV1             |           DGV2 
    Fruit       Qtt |          Fruit        Qtt       
   Apple          2 |          Apple         4
   Pear           3 |          Pear          6
   Wintermelon    1 |          Wintermelon   1
   Apple          2 |                    
   Pear           3 |
```

DGV1 column 1 move to DGV2 column1 without duplicate / unique
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
' Iterate through the rows in the source GridView (GridView1)
For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Dim data As String = row.Cells(0).Text ' Get the data from the first cell in the row
    Dim exists As Boolean = False ' Flag to track whether the data already exists in the destination GridView
    
    ' Search for the data in the destination GridView's data source
    For Each item As Object In GridView2.DataSource
        If item.ToString() = data Then
            exists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    ' If the data does not exist in the destination GridView, add it
    If Not exists Then
        Dim dataSource As List(Of String) = TryCast(GridView2.DataSource, List(Of String))
        dataSource.Add(data)
    End If
Next

' Bind the updated data source to the destination GridView
GridView2.DataSource = dataSource
GridView2.DataBind()
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help , appreciate it , trying now :))

Comment: but what if I have another column with a quantity ? is it the same code that I use would work ?